# $(this).attr(ID) is not working?

Tags: jquery

there is a input button as follow

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="test" value="CLICK ME" onclick="traverse();" />
</div>
```

this is the input button. which after being pressed should call traveres function. inside traverse function i am having                    `console.log($(this).attr("id"))`.

```
function traverse() {
    console.log(this.id);
}
```

Its not printing the id of the current input button.

any suggestion where i am doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass an argument  `this` in your `traverse function`, that will refer to the `current element`.

```js
function traverse(elem) {
  console.log(elem.id); //or $(elem).attr('id');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="test" value="CLICK ME" onclick="traverse(this);" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are passing along a reference to the object that is actually triggering the event using the following :

```
onclick="traverse(this);"
```

And then reference the object within your `traverse()` function call :

```
function traverse(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
}
```

Since you are using jQuery or at least mentioning it, you could accomplish this same behavior by creating an event listener for the click event using [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and jQuery will know the context behind the call :

```
$('#test').click(function(){
     console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

This will give you the id of the current element.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many inputs with different ids, you can trigger the click on one custom class:

```js
$(".click-me").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#console").append(id + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="test1" value="CLICK ME" class='click-me' />
  <input type="button" id="test2" value="CLICK ME" class='click-me' />
  <input type="button" id="test3" value="CLICK ME" class='click-me' />
  <input type="button" id="test4" value="CLICK ME" class='click-me' />
  <input type="button" id="test5" value="CLICK ME" class='click-me' />
</div>
<div id="console"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div>
 <input type="button" id="test" value="CLICK ME" onclick="traverse(this);" />
</div>`

Pass **this** as a self reference & access the **id** attribute later using the same reference later like below.

`function traverse(el) {
    console.log(el.id);
}`

for more reference visit this link [here](http://www.tinytute.com/jquery-text-input-get-attributes-by-id-name-or-class/)